# Write a representation of vector $v_3$ as a linear combination of all bases of V

Tags: linear-algebra

$$v_1= 
\begin{bmatrix}                         
  1 \\
  -2 \\
  1\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$v_2= 
\begin{bmatrix}                         
  2 \\
  -1 \\
 13 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$v_3= 
\begin{bmatrix}                         
  7 \\
  -9 \\
 -8 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$v_4= 
\begin{bmatrix}                         
  -6 \\
  7 \\
 9 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

It is already proved that $[v_1,v_2,v_3], [v_1,v_2,v_4],[v_2,v_3,v_4]$ are indepentent and a basis of $V$.

Then the question here is to write a representation of vector $v_3$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Thanks in advance

I am not sure that is it mean like in the first set $[v_1,v_2,v_3]$ change to $[v_1,v_2]=[v_3]$ or $[v_1,v_2,v_3]=[v_3]$
with using the $v_3$ as a linear combination?

Comment: When using $[v_1, v_2, v_3]$ as basis, $$v_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}_{[v_1, v_2, v_3]}$$ because $v_3 = 0 \cdot v_1 + 0 \cdot v_2 + 1 \cdot v_3$. Can you solve the other cases ($[v_1, v_2, v_4]$ and $[v_2, v_3, v_4]$)?

Comment: The fact that $v_3 = v_1 - v_4$ might help you.